# Fluent NHibernate spec, NHibernate 3.1, lazy loading and sql image column type

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, arrays, lazy-loading

Is there any know issues with lazy loading a property whose type is a byte[]? I've got an image column on a sql server 2008 db and I'm trying to map it into a byte[] property of a class. Since I don't want to load it always, I've configured it so that it uses lazy loading. Here's the code:

```
public class Documento : Entity, IHasAssignedId<Int32> {
    public virtual Byte[] Bytes { get; private set; }
    //...more properties
}
```

Here's the mapping:

```
Map( doc => doc.Bytes, "Documento" )
            .CustomSqlType( "image" )
            .CustomType<Byte[]>(  )
            .LazyLoad(  )
            .Not.Nullable( );
```

Now, the problem is that when I'm trying to check the mappings with PersistenceSpecification, I get an exception which says:

NHibernate.PropertyAccessException : Invalid Cast (check your mapping for property type mismatches); setter of Sra.Assistencias.Documento
  ----> System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'System.Byte[]'.

If I configure the property so that it doesn't use lazy loading or if I change its type to Object (leaving the db mapping as is), everything works out ok. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem comes from your mapping, not the lazy loading itself. Here's I map Image types in Fluent NHibernate:

```
interface IEmployee
{
    int Id { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    byte[] Image { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeMap : ClassMap<IEmployee>
{
    public EmployeeMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Image).CustomType("BinaryBlob");
    }
}
```

Where the "Image" column is of `Image` type using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Hello @binaryhowl.

Here's the mapping I'm using:

Map( doc => doc.Bytes, "Documento" )                .CustomSqlType( "BinaryBlob" )
                .CustomType<Byte[]>(  )
                .LazyLoad(  )
                .Not.Nullable( );

btw, I've also tried using "image" for the sql type, but it's still not working...any more thoughts?

thanks.

Comment: Could you try changing your mappings to the ones I suggest?